# Socket hang up on http.request to a Node.js MongoDb server

Tags: node.js

In my local pc I've set up a Node.js proxy server who makes request to a node.js RESTful MongoDb server, one is at port 8080 and the proxy at port 3000.
I can see in the RESTful server log that all the queries are sent back correctly to the proxy, but the proxy hang up throwing this error:

```
    events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
    Error: socket hang up
        at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
        at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1568:23)
        at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
        at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
        at _stream_readable.js:920:16
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

this is how I built my proxy request :

```
      var proxy = function(req, res, next) {
        try {
          var options = mapRequest(req);    
          var dbReq = http.request(options, function(dbRes) {
            var data = "";
            res.headers = dbRes.headers;
            dbRes.setEncoding('utf8');

            dbRes.on('data', function(chunk) { 
              data = data + chunk;
             });

            dbRes.on('end', function() {
              res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
              res.statusCode = dbRes.statusCode;
              res.httpVersion = dbRes.httpVersion;
              res.trailers = dbRes.trailers;
              res.send(data);
              res.end();
            });

          });

          dbReq.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));

        } catch (error) {
          console.log('ERROR: ', error.stack);
          res.json(error);
          res.end();
        }
       };
```

and these are the options sent to the MongoDB server:

```
    {
      "hostname":"127.0.0.1",
      "path":"//databases/db1/collections/documents?apiKey=134557676&l=5&sk=0",
      "method":"GET",
      "port":"8080",
      "headers":{
                "host":"127.0.0.1",
                "connection":"keep-alive",
                "accept":"application/json, text/plain ",
                "x-xsrf-token":"VPDlgN2iMWU2IXPIPH0aiwS5",
                "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36",
                "dnt":"1",
                "referer":"http://localhost:3000/documents",
                "accept-encoding":"gzip,deflate,sdch",
                "accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
                "cookie":"XSRF-TOKEN=VPDlgN2iMWU2IXPIPH0aiwS5; connect.sess=s%3Aj%3A%7B%22passport%22%3A%7B%22user%22%3A%225298bfa9e4b070e1c60fd84f%22%7D%2C%22_csrf%22%3A%22VPDlgN2iMWU2IXPIPH0aiwS5%22%7D.wc85bNSpJIl7KnCHOUXiG5V2e7SI9XR9EctByTtqhu4"
               }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution replacing `http.request()` with`http.get()`, apparently the socked hang up because the socket did not sent the connection end event within the timeout period.
A similar issue here: [NodeJS - What does "socket hang up" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)