# Why am I getting "Error socket hang up" response?

Tags: node.js, express, request, npm

I tried to scrape a website. And I am using the library https://github.com/request/request, but I get this error:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1476:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (http.js:1572:23)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13) +0ms
```

What is wrong here? I also tried to re-install the package, but I get same error... help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS - What does "socket hang up" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)

Answer (score 11):

I recently got this `socket hang up` problem. I researched for a few days until I found a solution that worked for me. So, maybe this can help.

It worked for me to add the `http(s)Agent` property with `keepAlive: true` in creating the http client. Here's an example of what it might look like:

```
const http = require('http')
http.request({
        method: 'GET',
        agent: http.Agent({keepAlive:true}),
        host: 'www.google.com',
    })
```

This property is responsible for managing the sockets for client-side http connections. The justification for using this property can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent).

I also found an answer on the stackoverflow that also covers the subject, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649566/difference-between-nodejs-new-agent-and-http-keep-alive-header/58332910#58332910).

So, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

check the bellow link
for the source code

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ba048e72b02e17f0c73e0dcb7d37e76a03327c5a/lib/_http_client.js#L164

or check the following question

[NodeJS - What does "socket hang up" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)