# Error: socket hang up in Node JS using request-promise module

Tags: node.js, request

I am getting socket hang up eror message while sending request. As per observation request is getting processed but at the time of sending response, I am getting below response:

```
 {
   "success":false,
   "error":{
     "name":"RequestError","message":"Error: socket hang up","cause":{"code":"ECONNRESET"},
     "error":{"code":"ECONNRESET"},
     "options":{"uri":"request url","simple":true,"resolveWithFullResponse":false,"transform2xxOnly":false}
   }
}
```

I am using below code:

```
var options = {
  uri: 'request url',
};
request(options).then(function(data) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      data: data
    });     
 })
 .catch(function (err) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      error: err,
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS - What does "socket hang up" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Can you please share your URI if not confidential and your handler code to debug more?

Comment: @node_saini URL is confidential so I cannot share it.. But the problem is related to timeout. Process is taking upto 6 minutes and request is not waiting for that and giving this error.

If you have experienced timeout issue then you can share your solution

Comment: You can try using `server.timeout` or `server.keepAliveTimeout`

Comment: @charmizala i dont think its a time out problem else you would have seen `ETIMEDOUT` , but im also facing the same problem my api call works via `request-promise` module perfectly and just once a week i see the error `ECONNRESET`, which is new, it never use to happen.

Comment: almost feels like blaming module `request-promise` as i see people move away from it and it fixes the problem.