# Socket error node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, swi-prolog

I'm getting a error of socket end, I'm trying to do a http request (getPrologFarm2) to get info from prolog and it's giving me this error, I already did one before just like this and it did work.

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:254:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:346:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Code:

```
router.route('/farmacias')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    var info;

    client.methods.getFarmacias(function (data, res) {
      info = data;
    });

    sleep(2000);

    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var list = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < info.length; i++) {
      if (hours < 12) {
        if (info[i].restricaoTemporal == 'manha') {
          list.push(info[i].nome);
        }
      } else {
        if (info[i].restricaoTemporal == 'tarde') {
          list.push(info[i].nome);
        }
      }
    }

    var info1;

    client.methods.getPrologFarm2(function (data, res) {
      info1 = data
    });

    res.json(info1);

  });
```

Comment: please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)

Comment: You'll never get your data this way. You're returning asynchronous data that's not here yet.

Comment: @JeremyThille even with a sleep I couldn't get the data because of the socket error.

Comment: But I can see no socket-related code whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you code inside `.get(function (req, res)` 
 throws an unhandled exception and the socket crashes.

As mentioned by @Jeremy Thille in the comments you have some Asynchronous calls and `sleep` is not the answer to that. Maybe thats the issue because `info1` would be `undefined` when you try to convert it into json.

First you should try to add a `try/catch` block at the whole `get` function to check what the error is, like this

```
router.route('/farmacias')
  .get(function(req, res) {

    try {
      //your code

    } catch (e) {
      res.send(e)
    }

  });
```

Secondly, since you are not using `Promises` and have callback your code should look more like this.

```
    router.route('/farmacias')
      .get(function(req, res) {
        client.methods.getPrologFarm2(function(data, res) {
          res.json(data);
        });
      });
```

or like this

```
router.route('/farmacias')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    client.methods.getFarmacias(function(data, res) {

      var hours = new Date().getHours();
      var list = [];

      for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (hours < 12) {
          if (data[i].restricaoTemporal == 'manha') {
            list.push(data[i].nome);
          }
        } else {
          if (data[i].restricaoTemporal == 'tarde') {
            list.push(data[i].nome);
          }
        }
      }

      res.json(list);

    });

  });
```