# Socket hangs up in supertest mongodb node REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing a REST API for an assignment and currently I have few endpoints and I'm writing test cases on the go. Strange thing happen when I make a test to check if the database is connected correctly. I have several `GET` and `POST` methods. The `POST` always passes if I pass valid data. So I moved forward making a test to check the database connection.

When I place the `POST` method before `GET`, the test "API connects with mongodb" passes.

```
describe('Admin adds a new user', function () {
    it('Request to add a user without authorization', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .post('/api/admin/user/add')
            .send({
                username: "Padmal1",
                password: "abc123",
                isAdmin: false
            })
            .expect(400, done);
    });
});

describe('API connects with mongodb', function () {
    it('Successful database connection', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .get('/api')
            .expect(200, done);
    });
});
```

[image: all tests passing when post before get]

But when I put `GET` before `POST`, the test "API connects with mongodb" fails saying `socket hang up`

```
describe('API connects with mongodb', function () {
    it('Successful database connection', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .get('/api')
            .expect(200, done);
    });
});

describe('Admin adds a new user', function () {
    it('Request to add a user without authorization', function (done) {
        request(app)
            .post('/api/admin/user/add')
            .send({
                username: "Padmal1",
                password: "abc123",
                isAdmin: false
            })
            .expect(400, done);
    });
});
```

[image: test fail when get before post]

Following are the methods used in this API;

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

var db = undefined;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/posdb',
    { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(client => {
        db = client.db('posdb');
        db.collection('col_users').createIndex({ "username": 1 }, { unique: true });
    })
    .catch(res => {
        console.log(res.name);
    });

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    // Test endpoint to test database connection
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
        "status": "API is up and running with a Mongo DB @ " +
            db.serverConfig.s.host + ':' + db.serverConfig.s.port
    }));
});

app.post('/api/admin/user/add', (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.headers.authorization) {
            // TODO: Verify authentication
            try {
                if (req.body.username) {
                    db.collection('col_users').insertOne(req.body, function (err, r) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.writeHead(403, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                            res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: "Duplicate username ..." }));
                        } else {
                            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                            res.end(JSON.stringify({ _id: r.insertedId }));
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                    res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: "No user to add ..." }));
                }
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
                    res.writeHead(503, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                    res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: "JSON format seems wrong ..." }));
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new ReferenceError;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
            res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: "Database seems out of our hands ..." }));
        } else if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
            res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ error: "Invalid user request ..." }));
        }
    }
});
```

I did some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean) on this issue and couldn't get any idea related to it. I'm very new to NodeJS development though. When I try the link in a browser, it seems working fine giving expected results.

[image: web browser]

I also tried adding connection:keep-alive to headers but didn't work. Only this works is placing `GET` test after `POST` test. What could be the issue? Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: This might not be the issue, but it's worth noting that node promises are asynchronous so your `MongoClient.connect` code may or may not complete before you try to use `db`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess that's the issue here. I'm going to switch to mongoose instead :)

Comment: @Padmal what was the resolution on this? Also as you most likely know now you still have to await mongoose on the connect portion. I have socket hangup on GET and DELETE.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione I had to keep the order of functions inverted. That is `GET` after `POST`. Sorry I didn't get to pursue this issue any further.