# Error: socket hang up in Nodejs while inserting bulk records in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, remote-access, node-mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmzUN.png)Getting error **Error: socket hang up** while executing my script about migrate data from mongo to MySQL via NodeJs. Although, I'm inserting 1000 of records in chunks. Somehow script is terminating and getting error.
I inspected in the process so I came to know node and mongo are eating 120% CPU memory.
One more thing, I'm using a remote connection of MySQL. so node server and Mysql hosted at different places.
How can I resolve this error?[image]

Comment: CPU memory? I doubt you mean L1/L2 cache. So which is it? Which is it hanging up from, MySQL or Mongo? Is there anything in the MySQL or Mongo logs?

Comment: You may find clues to resolve your problem in this URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean  -  if not, please post your code that causes the start of the log shipping activity.  And check your Skype account, please.