# NextJS getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I own a website which has a getInitialProps for fetching data from my express API. Now this request comes from the server IP, which later on if and when the website becomes popular, eventually there will be errors "socket hang up" causing the website to go down.

This already happens during DDoS attacks. Does anyone have any advice on what I could do here to handle this?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean