# Service+deployment on GKE hangs up after 30 minutes

Tags: flask, kubernetes, timeout, postman, google-kubernetes-engine

I tried to look up for solutions, but I am probably not asking the correct question.

I have a service performing long running tasks deployed inside a GKE cluster (a flask app served through gunicorn). When I make a request, Postman returns a `Error: socket hang up` after 30 minutes. What am I not considering? Is the behaviour due to the service in front of the deployment?

My chain of services is as follows:

- Consumer: Postman, setting for timeout=0 - i.e. infinite - and header `"Connection":"keep-alive"` is passed
- `loadBalancer` (exposed) proxy: node+express, timeout=7200000 (ms)
- `clusterIP` (internal) service: python+flask, gunicorn timeout=7200 (s)

Service is started through `CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT start:app --workers $NO_WORKERS --threads $NO_THREADS --timeout $TIMEOUT`

The service has been deployed with the following yaml file by `kubectl apply -f`:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: layers-api
  labels: 
    app: layers-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: layers-api
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: layers-api
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: PORT
          value: '4000'
        - name: NO_WORKERS
          value: '2'
        - name: NO_THREADS
          value: '2'
        - name: TIMEOUT
          value: '7200'
        # ...other env vars... 
        name: layers-api
        image: [DOMAIN]/[PROJECT]/[IMAGE]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 4000
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/v1/healthz
            port: 4000
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/v1/healthz
            port: 4000
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: layers-api
  labels:
    app: layers-api
    tier: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: layers-api
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 4000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 4000
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
---
```

Thank you for spending your time to help.

C

EDIT: [this the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p10x.png) from the proxy server. Moreover, I use this proxy for another routing (to a managed cloud run service - beta timeout of 3600 seconds) and this does not hang up after 30 minutes).

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean/27835115#27835115)? You can try to use another service and see if you are getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you @AlexG! I indeed had a look, but I am not sure / I can't understand on how this applies to my case. The proxy server does not have the _http_client.js module (in edit). Also, admittedly I am more familiar with Python than JS, which I mostly use for proxies - such in this case.

Comment: Have you tested it with a different service?

Comment: I tried it on Cloud Run + GKE and it gives me the same problem. However, if I deploy it on Cloud Run (managed) the hang up error disappears and runs up to 1 hour [CR beta](shorturl.at/jpNTX).

Comment: Try upgrading the machine type of your nodes. Are there any other services using the port 4000?

Comment: Only this service is on 4000. The cluster is versioned 1.16.15-gke.6000. I will update it as I have a chance to do it (sure to not tear down anyone else :-D ). Thank you for your help @Alex G!